# WaitForExit process in Windows XP versus Windows 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a .net console that is working perfectly fine in windows 7 but for some reason if i run the same exact code in windows XP, I am getting errow message "No Process is associated with this object", it then points to `prc.WaitForExit();`

The code is below:

```
   string path;

   path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
           System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);

   Process prc = new Process();  
   prc.StartInfo.FileName = path + "\\Process2.bat";
   prc.Start();

   prc.WaitForExit();
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
   Console.WriteLine("{0} Task Process2 completed with process ID {1} and return code {2}. ", DateTime.Now.ToString(), prc.Id, prc.ExitCode.ToString());

   System.IO.StreamWriter file =
      new System.IO.StreamWriter(logpath + "\\logfile.txt", true);
        file.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Task Process2 completed with process ID " + prc.Id + " and return code " + prc.ExitCode.ToString());

  file.Close();
```

Please help. Any help is greatly apprecaited.

Comment: Can you confirm you are running the same version of .NET on both machines

Comment: Yes, i'm using the same VS 2010 on two machines.

Comment: VS 2010 is your IDE, not the .NET your running. You probably have 4.0

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on the prc.WaitForExit() and look at the task manager to make sure that this process really exists?

Comment: @Kate It does exist. But actually, I figured out my problem. For some reason, this seems to be windows compatibility issue. When i change the prc.StartInfo.FileName = path + "\\Process2.bat"; INTO >>> prc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\BatchProcesses\bin\Debug\Process2.bat"; It actually worked. Weird.